# Why isn't one Async project recognized by the calling project, while a similar project is recognized?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have two projects which are being called by a separate project.  One, FormDataLibrary works fine but the new on IMDBData is not being recognized by the calling project.

```
using FormDataLibrary;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IMDBData;

namespace GetMovieData
{
    public partial class FormMovieData : Form
    {
        readonly string path = @"\\video";


        public FormMovieData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormMetadata_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ReportProgress(object sender, FormDataModel e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.PercentageComplete;
            labelNumberOfFiles.Text = $"Total Files - {e.TotalFiles}";
            labelCurrentFileCount.Text = $"Current File Count - {e.CurrentFileNumber}";
            labelCurrentFilename.Text = $"Current File Name - {e.CurrentFile}";
            labelStartTime.Text = $"Start Time - {e.StartTime}";
            labelElapsed.Text = $"Elapsed - {e.ElapsedTime}";
            labelETA.Text = $"ETA - {e.ETA}";
        }

        private async void GetMovieDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchPath;
            searchPath = path;
            labelNumberOfFiles.Text = searchPath;
            await GetIMDBFilesAsync();
            await GetMovieMetadataAsync(searchPath);
        }

        private async Task GetMovieMetadataAsync(string path)
        {
            GetMovieDataButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CadetBlue;
            labelStatus.Text = "Start";
            Progress<FormDataModel> progress = new Progress<FormDataModel>();
            labelStatus.Text = "Call report Progress";
            progress.ProgressChanged += ReportProgress;
            labelStatus.Text = "times";
            Boolean GetTimes = false;
            if (MovieTimes.Checked)
            {
                GetTimes = true;
            }
            else
            {
                GetTimes = false;
            }
            labelStatus.Text = "Await";
            await Task.Run(() => GetMovieMetadata.GettingMovieMetadata(path, progress, GetTimes));
            labelStatus.Text = "End";
            GetMovieDataButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        private async Task GetIMDBFilesAsync()
        {
           await Task.Run(() => GetIMDBData.GettingIMDBData());
        }

    }
}
```

This is the IMDBProject as it stands right now

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IMDBData
{
    public class GetIMDBData
    {
        public static void GettingIMDBData()
            {
            }
    }
}
```

What you can't see here is that using IMDBData; and
GetIMDBData in await Task.Run(() => GetIMDBData.GettingIMDBData());
have red underlines.

Im afraid all this is information overload but thank you for any help

Comment: For future reference, please think about how you select your code to copy into a question. Like so many people, you have clear placed the mouse at the first character of the first line and then dragged to the end, which means that the first line has no leading whitespace while every other line does. If you're going to leave the whitespace on every other line, leave if on the first one too. There's no excuse for leaving it on any though. The question editor could remove it for you with 2 seconds effort or you can hold the ALT key down while selecting an arbitrary block of text in VS.

Comment: Also, maybe don't submit your question if part of the text is inside the code block. Look at the preview before submitting and don't submit if it's a mess.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue with your comment but understand it.  What is the issue about not having the leading whitespace?  I attempted to include the relevant code.

Comment: Having a big chunk of leading whitespace on your code makes it unnecessarily harder to read. Most notably, it requires additional horizontal scrolling, especially on a phone. Relevant code is good. Properly formatted code is better. You should endeavour to make your code as easy to read as possible. Do everything you can to help us help you.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". Right now the title looks like a couple of tags with a tiny amount of text.

Comment: Are these two projects in the same solution? How EXACTLY is the first project referencing the second?

Comment: Yes, they are two projects in the same solution.  Or I should say three projects.  GetMovieData reference both GetIMDBData and FormDataLibrary.  I am using the Using statements at the top to bring GetIMDBData and FormDataLibrary into GetMovieData.

Comment: Please check in the References if there is a warning sign on the IMDBData reference. Also if it's .NET Framework project then check how this reference is specified in *.csproj file. It might be a reference to DLL instead of a reference to project in the same solution. In this case you might have various weird effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a project that contains types that will be available to other projects then you need to create a library of some sort. In your case, probably a Class Library project. Make sure that it targets .NET Framework, .NET Core (.NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core) or .NET Standard, depending on where you want to use it.

You can then add a reference to the project itself in other projects in the same solution. You can also add the existing projects to other solutions if appropriate, then reference the project there too. Otherwise, you must build the project and reference the compiled DLL. You also have the option of generating a NuGet package and installing that into other projects.

Just like any library you refer to, in order to access the types in contains, you must either fully-qualify the type names with the namespace or else import the namespace. With regards to namespaces, I suggest that you come up with a system now and stick to it. I recommend that you decide on a "company name" and use that as the root to all names. You should then name the solution after the product and the project after the component. In my case, my company name is Wunnell and I have a product named StudioPartner so I might have a class library named Wunnell.StudioPartner.Service and the root namespace in that library would have the same name, so all types would be in that namespace.

Also note that, in order to be accessed outside the assembly it's declared in, a type must be declared `public`. You should do so explicitly for every such type. If I'm not mistaken, types without an explicit access modifier are implicitly `internal`, which means only accessible within the assembly they are declared in.

Comment: The namespace is included "using FormDataLibrary;" and one class is recognized but the other is not.  Both are in the FormDataLibrary;  I am working this in the evenings outside of work hours so I will look into your first paragraph most likely tomorrow.  Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @RoyHull, most likely one class is explicitly marked `public` while the other is not. Make sure EVERYTHING has an explicit access modifier and that they are appropriate to how you want the type or member to be used. I will modify my answer to include this information.

Comment: I attempted to follow what was suggested but obviously I am missing something.  I didn't want to overload with too much info but I think I need to paint a bigger picture.  So I am going to open a new question with more information.  Thank you for your comments an I hope you check out my new post

Comment: @RoyHull, you probably ought to have edited this question, if it's the same problem. If you've already created the new question, you should delete this one. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ensure the new question satisfies that requirement. If that requires you to create new projects with minimal functionality then you should do so. You probably ought to have done so already. When people remove the irrelevant clutter, they can often see the problem themselves and either fix it or at least explain it more clearly.